# I'm not able to mock a method, using mockito, to return a Flow using flow builder

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockito

I've been trying to mock, using mockito, a method that returns a Flow through a flow builder. That's my code:

```kotlin
package br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc

import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.verify
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.whenever
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.UnconfinedTestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.InjectMocks
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MockitoTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val changeMainDispatcherRule = ChangeMainDispatcherRule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockRepository: MiniRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var viewModel: MiniViewModel

    @Test
    fun `mock repository flow`() = runTest {
        whenever(mockRepository.getFlow()).thenReturn(flow {
            emit("fake service data")
        })
        viewModel.data.observeForever {}

        val value = viewModel.data.value

        verify(mockRepository).getFlow()
        assertEquals("fake service data", value)
    }
}

class MiniViewModel(
    booksService: MiniRepository
) {
    val data: LiveData<String> = booksService.getFlow()
        .catch {
            throw RuntimeException("exception on flow emission")
        }
        .asLiveData()
}

class MiniRepository {
    fun getFlow() = flow { emit("service data") }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class ChangeMainDispatcherRule(
    private val dispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(),
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

And here is the failing test stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Test worker @coroutine#2" java.lang.RuntimeException: exception on flow emission
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MiniViewModel$data$1.invokeSuspend(MockitoTest.kt:62)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MiniViewModel$data$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MiniViewModel$data$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catch$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:114)
    at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(FlowLiveData.kt:80)
    at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invoke(FlowLiveData.kt)
    at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invoke(FlowLiveData.kt)
    at androidx.lifecycle.BlockRunner$maybeRun$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineLiveData.kt:177)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.lifecycle.BlockRunner.maybeRun(CoroutineLiveData.kt:175)
    at androidx.lifecycle.CoroutineLiveData.onActive(CoroutineLiveData.kt:241)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.changeActiveCounter(LiveData.java:405)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:481)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:234)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invokeSuspend(MockitoTest.kt:48)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:212)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:112)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(TestBuilders.kt:211)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt$createTestResult$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:12)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:166)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:154)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:147)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest.mock repository flow(MockitoTest.kt:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [CoroutineId(2), "coroutine#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@61fafb74, Dispatchers.Main]

expected:<fake service data> but was:<null>
Expected :fake service data
Actual   :null
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<fake service data> but was:<null>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invokeSuspend(MockitoTest.kt:53)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest$mock repository flow$1.invoke(MockitoTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:212)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:112)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(TestBuilders.kt:211)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt$createTestResult$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:12)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:166)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:154)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:147)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bmelocarvalho.mockitopoc.MockitoTest.mock repository flow(MockitoTest.kt:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

The problem is that the test is failing because for some reason the catch block in the ViewModel is executed. And what's even more strange is that if I remove the assert the code passes with mockito verifying that the mocked method was called. 
Does someone have a clue about what is happening? 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: [Here is a simple project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hk36Sgh7ao3ir0nJDk_Pzka_zBgg2zqz/view?usp=sharing) to run the code.

Comment: I'm confused, actually.  It looks like your code _should_ throw even with the modified flow.

Comment: Hi Louis, me too .
What do you mean by modified flow?